# How can I check if an object method exists?

Tags: php, oop, object, methods, isset

I want to use some code only if the method `getProductgroup` exists.
My first approach:

```
if(isset($item->getProductgroup())){
 $productgroupValidation = 0;
 $productgroupId = $item->getProductgroup()->getUuid();
 foreach($dataField->getProductgroup() as $productgroup){
   $fieldProductgroup = $productgroup->getUuid();
   if($productgroupId==$fieldProductgroup){
       $productgroupValidation = 1;
  }
}
```

I got the error message:

> Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you
>   can use "null !== expression" instead)

```
if(($item->getProductgroup())!==NULL){
     $productgroupValidation = 0;
     $productgroupId = $item->getProductgroup()->getUuid();
     foreach($dataField->getProductgroup() as $productgroup){
       $fieldProductgroup = $productgroup->getUuid();
       if($productgroupId==$fieldProductgroup){
           $productgroupValidation = 1;
      }
    }
```

But like this I also get an error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getProductgroup" of class
>   "App\Entity\Documents".

Comment: You wouldn't believe it but `method_exists()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `method_exists` to check if the method is existing in a class or not. for example

```
if(method_exists('CLASS_NAME', 'METHOD_NAME') ) 
   echo "it does exist!"; 
else 
   echo "nope, it is not there...";
```

In your code try

```
if(method_exists($item, 'getProductgroup')){
$productgroupValidation = 0;
if(method_exists($item->getProductgroup(), 'getUuid'))
{
   $productgroupId = $item->getProductgroup()->getUuid();
   foreach($dataField->getProductgroup() as $productgroup)
   {
        $fieldProductgroup = $productgroup->getUuid();
        if($productgroupId==$fieldProductgroup){
            $productgroupValidation = 1;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask a question? I have some cases where the  `getProductgroup()` exists, but not `getProductgroup()->getUuid()`. So I would more need to check if `getProductgroup()->getUuid()` exists

Comment: @marila yes you need to apply check for the same as well

Comment: I did it like this `if(method_exists($item, 'getUuid')){`  but still get the error message `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getUuid" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".`

Comment: @marila answer has been updated.

Comment: ah thank you, I just did not understand how to do it! :)